# Finding successor, predecessor faster than BST

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I am looking for a data structure with the following properties:
For a list of integers (such that x > 1, and x < U, where U is a large integer).

It can perform: `predecessor(x)`, `successor(x)`, `insert(x)`, `delete(x)`.

This can be implemented with a binary search tree, and all operations would be O(log n). Well, according to my professor, this can be implemented with `successor` and predecessor in O(log log U) time, and `insert` and `delete` in O(log U) time.

It requires an array of size U, and a binary search tree. Anyone know what this algorithm is?

Comment: Van Emde Boas tree, x-fast trie and y-fast trie all do that in that time complexity, y-fast trie also adheres to your space complexity. Actually iirc it requires ```|x|``` space not ```|U|```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Y-Fast Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) and [X-Fast Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-fast_trie)

I believe these are what you are looking for.

From **Wikipedia**:

Y-Fast Trie:

> In computer science, a y-fast trie is a data structure for storing integers from a bounded > > domain. It supports exact and predecessor or successor queries in time O(log log M), using O(n) > space, where n is the number of stored values and M is the maximum value in the domain.

X-Fast Trie:

> In computer science, an x-fast trie is a data structure for storing integers from a bounded > domain. It supports exact and predecessor or successor queries in time O(log log M), using O(n > log M) space, where n is the number of stored values and M is the maximum value in the domain.